# my currency converter question is i a need function to convert rand(ZAR) to pound, dollar, and euro

Tags: javascript, html, currency

I need to put in a certain amount of rands and get back euro, pound, and dollar.

The rest of my code does have the link to the javascript file. I've only put the dollar() function in for now because I was at least trying to get one to work but it didn't so I need help.

```js
function dollar() {
  let money = document.getElementbyId("rand").value;
  const $ = 15.5734;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = $ * money;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Rand: <input type="number" id="rand">
  <input id="dollar" type="button" onclick="dollar()" value="dollar"/>
  <input id="euro" type="button" onclick="euro()" value="euro">
  <input id ="pound" type="button" onclick="pound()" value="pound">
</form>
        
<p> result is: <span id="result"></span> </p>
```

Comment: Your doing the function for event onclick, so the function is being called and the user haven’t typed anything yet.

Comment: Note: Javascript is not the same as Java.

Comment: Not sure if you directly copy and pasted or not, but the first getElementById was not properly capitalized (as the answer states), so it won’t work. Also put in an if statement making sure the forms not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just needed to change function name and change `document.getElementbyId` to `document.getElementById`

```html
<form>
  Rand: <input type="number" id="rand">
  <input id="dollar" type="button" onclick="todollar()" value="dollar"/>
  <input id="euro" type="button" onclick="euro()" value="euro">
  <input id ="pound" type="button" onclick="pound()" value="pound">
</form>
        
<p> result is: <span id="result"></span> </p>
<script>
function todollar() {
  let money = document.getElementById("rand").value;
  const $ = 15.5734;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = $ * money;
}
</script>
```